# How to use parameter file to execute windows batch command line?

Tags: if-statement, cmd

I have a batch file:

---

```
@echo off

set username=Admin

set password=Admin

echo %username%

echo %password%
```

---

Now i want to use parameter file (ex: "Parameter.txt" )

```
username=Admin

password=Admin
```

And batch cript(ex: "Test.bat")

```
echo %username%

echo %password%
```

How to "Test.bat" can use parameter file "Parameter.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming `parameter.txt` has the indicated format,

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("parameter.txt") do set "%%a"
echo %username%
echo %password%
```

The `for /f` command will read the input file (`usebackq` necessary to properly quote the input filename, `delims=` to not include any delimiter and read full lines) and *for each line* (that will be stored in the `for` replaceable parameter `%%a`), execute the code in the `do` clause: a `set` command with the name and value of the variable retrieved from the file and stored in `%%a`

Comment: Thanks very much, it work OK! It very userful for my job